# Does cardinality in database return numeric values?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am re-engineering code written in the SQL, and I got a use of cardinality in an `order by` clause. So on which basis it is going to order the records?

e.g.

```
ORDER BY
      cardinality(emp_ids),
      earliest_due_date
```

where `emp_ids` are prepared like this

```
 CAST(
       collect(employee.emp_id)
       AS
       NumberList
     ) AS emp_ids
```

Comment: What's unclear about the statement "*CARDINALITY returns the **number** of elements in a nested table*" in the manual?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions022.htm#SQLRF06305) that the return is numeric:

> CARDINALITY returns the number of elements in a nested table. The
>   return type is NUMBER. If the nested table is empty, or is a null
>   collection, then CARDINALITY returns NULL.

So, your order by will return the `emp_ids` table with the least number of rows in it first (empty ones as it will return null will come last).